# Текстовое поле

Tags: mysql

Доброе время суток! У меня вопрос следующий: создана таблица, из 2 полей, тип первого поля `char`, а тип второго хотел бы узнать. Надо сделать так, чтобы в него загружалась информация из текстового файла, находящегося на диске D под название `1.txt`. Какой тип поля выбрать и какую команду прописать следует!? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
`myText` text NOT NULL default '',
```

Answer (score 1):

Кроме TEXT можете еще взять тип BLOB и грузить туда файлы целиком.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="readfile.php">FILE<input type="file" name="file"><input type="submit"></form>
```

Это `HTML`.

```
<?php
$tmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$name=$_FILES['file']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($tmp, "uploads/".$name);

$handle = fopen("uploads/$name", "r");
while (!feof($handle)) {
$buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
echo $buffer;
}
?>
```

А это `PHP (readfile.php)`. Вроде все работает :-))

Осталось закинуть содержимое `$buffer` в БД.